# Creating Dropdown Dynamically - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to develop a JS function that creates a new row each time a new record is added to a database (from a different program that checks periodically). Right now I can get the function to check the db, add the record to the table and display it dynamically. The first column is the user id and the second column is where I'm running into issues. I would like to include a dropdown, but I'm not sure how to add options to it. I have the dropdown in the second column, but there are no options to choose from. Anyone have some suggestions?

```
function addRow(tableID, user) {

var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");

     tabbody=document.getElementsByTagName("tbody").item(2);
     cell1 = document.createElement("TD");
     cell2 = document.createElement("TD");
     textnode1=document.createTextNode(user);
     //textnode2=document.createTextNode("morecontent");
     textnode2=document.createElement("select");
     textnode2.setAttribute('id', 'focus');
     textnode2.options.add(opt);
     cell1.appendChild(textnode1);
     cell2.appendChild(textnode2);
     row.appendChild(cell1);
     row.appendChild(cell2);
     tabbody.appendChild(row);

    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
```

Here is the HTML that it is sent to:

```
        <th colspan="2">Pending Alerts</th>
    <tr>
       <th>User</th>
       <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After

```
textnode2 = document.createElement("select");
```

you need to do something like

```
var op = new Option();
op.value = 1;
op.text = "First entry";
textnode2.options.add(op);
```

and repeat for your desired entries.

Comment: How do I define option()? I'm getting an error that says "ReferenceError: option is not defined"

Comment: Nevermind. I got it. I had to change `new option()` to `document.createElement("option");` Thanks for your help!

Comment: Should have been `Option()` - capital O

Comment: nice of @EugenRieck could fix it, edits must be at least 6 characters ;)

Comment: Done! Sorry for that.

Answer (score 7):

I like this method.

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById("MyDropDownList");
var opt = document.createElement("option"); 
opt.text = 'something';
opt.value = 'somethings value';
dropdown.options.add(opt);
```