# Binding values to HTML dropdownlist using JQuery with ASP.NET MVC WebAPI - Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to populate values for html drowpdown using JQuery from webapi url. JSON returns value and I've verified it using alert function. But, when I bind those into dropdown it is not populating the values.

Chrome developer tool console shows err:

### "Cannot read property '0' of undefined ".

```
@section scripts {

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var testDdl = $('#test');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Values",
            type: "Get",
            success: function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    testDdl.append($("<option/>"), {
                        value: this.data[i],
                        html: this.data[i]
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(msg) { alert(msg); }
        });
    });
</script> }

<body>

<form>
    <select id="test"></select>
</form> </body>
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275972/creating-dropdown-dynamically-javascript

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` give you if you place it inside the success callback?

Comment: I tried the above link  opt.text = data[i];
                        opt.value = data[i];
                        testDdl.options.add(opt);. But, I am getting "Cannot read property 'add' of undefined"  error.

Comment: I do have 2 values in my json. So, console gives "Value1, value2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are certain that the data object is correct (it would have to just be an array of strings) this should work:

```
success: function(data) {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       var option = $("<option/>");
       option.attr("value", data[i]).text(data[i]);
       testDdl.append(option);
    }
 },
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/aq8X5/5/

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the result with `$.each`.

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(value);
}
```

What you should pass to `testDdl.append` depends on what your JSON looks like.