# Dynamically add drop down list

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, dynamically-generated

I can dynamically add text boxes like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id='item'></div>

<input name='add' type='button' id='add' value='Add Item'/>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

var item = document.getElementById('item');

var stopper=0;

document.getElementById('add').onclick = function () {

stopper=stopper+1;

  var input = document.createElement('input'),
      div = document.createElement('div');
  input.type = "text";
  input.setAttribute("name", "item[]");
  input.setAttribute("class", "item");

  div.appendChild(input);
  //...

  item.appendChild(div);

};
</script>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rF54/)

How can I do this? Instead of *text box*, I want to dynamically generate a *drop down* (`<select>`). And the *option* of the drop down would be coming from my *SQL database*.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275972/creating-dropdown-dynamically-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Replace `createElement('input')` with `createElement('select')` and then create additional `option` elements the same way: `var opt1 = document.createElement('option')` and Set the attributes (`value` that goes to the server and `text` that the user sees, usually) on each element. Then append each `option` object to your `select` object, and append the `select` object into the DOM as you are doing with your `input` object now.

Here's an example using an array of animals, and sending the first letter as the value to the server:

```
var items = ['aardvark', 'bear', 'cat', 'donkey'];
var values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var sel = document.createElement('select');
sel.setAttribute('name', 'item[]');
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.setAttribute('text', items[i]);
    opt.setAttribute('value', values[i]);
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}
// ... from here on, set any other attributes, like classes
// Then and add the select object to the DOM:
item.appendChild(sel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi please try this code.

```
        <html>
    <body>

    <div id='item'></div>

    <input name='add' type='button' id='add' value='Add Item'/>

    </body>
    </html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var item = document.getElementById('item');

        var stopper=0;

        document.getElementById('add').onclick = function () {

        stopper=stopper+1;

         var select = document.createElement('select'),
              div = document.createElement('div');

          select.setAttribute("name", "item[]");
          select.setAttribute("class", "item");
            //this is just an example. You need to replace this code with ajax that is fetching 
//from the Database.. and please use jquery it makes your work easier.
            var  count = getRandomInt(1, 5);
            for(var a=1; a<=count; a++) {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                 var t =  randon_val();
            //end
              option.setAttribute("value",t);
              option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(t));
                select.appendChild(option);
            }



          div.appendChild(select);
          item.appendChild(div);

        };

        function getRandomInt(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }

        function randon_val()
        {
            var text = "";
            var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

            for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
                text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

            return text;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This link will be helpful.
[How to dynamically create a drop-down list with JavaScript and jQuery](https://www.techiedelight.com/dynamically-create-drop-down-list-javascript/)  Also you can try this way.

```js
function addItemToList(){
        //create label for the dropdown
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.innerHTML = "Select an Item: "

        //dropdown values
        var valuerArray = ["V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"];
        var textArray = ["TEXT1", "TEXT2", "TEXT3", "TEXT4"];

        //create dropdown
        var select = document.createElement("select");
        select.name = "dropdownName";
        select.id = "dropdownId"

        //dropdown items
        for (var i = 0; i < valuerArray.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = valuerArray[i];
            option.text = textArray[i];
            select.appendChild(option);
        }

        //add label and dropdown to HTML containers
        document.getElementById("labelContainer").appendChild(label);
        document.getElementById("itemContainer").appendChild(select);
    }
```

```html
<HTML>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><div id="labelContainer"></div></td>
    <td><div id="itemContainer"></div></td>
    <td><input name='add' type='button' id='add' value='Add Item' onclick='addItemToList()' /></div></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: The answer also added